# How to implement a multipurpose pointer to class member function?

Tags: c++, class, methods, pointer-to-member

I wish to create one pointer to any class getter, which are returning values with different types

```
class MyClass
{
private:
   int i;
   string str;
public:
   int getI() { return i }
   string getStr() { return str }
}

int main
{
   MyClass *obj = new MyClass;
   //procedure to create multipurpose *pointerToAnyMethod
   //...

   // Set pointer to getI() method
   int gotI = obj->*pointerToAnyMethod() // return I

   // Set pointer to getStr() method
   string gotStr = obj->*pointerToAnyMethod() // return Str
}
```

Would be glad to any ideas.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need this?

Comment: I don't understand how the method pointerToAnyMethod should act. What do you expect it to return? why it returns an int on the first call, and string for second? (with no arguments)

Comment: Looks somewhat like a [`tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or [`variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).